# Concatenating NumPy arrays with specified values in between

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to concatenate numpy arrays in the same way as `hstack`. I would like to put a gap, let's say of `10`, between every array in the resultant one.

Any solution without loop?

> EDIT1

The example is:

```
arr1=numpy.array([ [1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]])
arr2=numpy.array([ [7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]])
```

The value I specify is `0` and with a gap of `5` the result will be:

```
[[1,  2,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  5,  6],
 [7,  8,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 11, 12]]
```

> EDIT2

I need a general solution and the arrays to be concatenated could be more than 2

> EDIT3

The width of the array, that is, the number of rows will remain the same but the number of columns may vary for each array

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "a gap of 10"? Can you show an example?

Comment: the value between each concatenation

Comment: I tried hstak, I am modifying it with an exmaple

Comment: Edit your question and show expected output for given input?

Comment: by the way before someone downvotes, they can try to understand the problem

Comment: To clarify: do you want a general solution which concatenates an arbitrary number of arrays (more than two) with gaps?

Comment: yes more than two with gaps

Comment: Would all the input arrays be of the same shape?

Comment: the height is the same, width could be different

Comment: I have edited the question, its EDIT3

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
np.hstack((arr1, np.zeros((arr1.shape[0], 5)), arr2))
```

If you have a list of arrays instead, you have to somehow insert the arrays of zeros in your array list before you call hstack. Here's a trick using itertools.chain that does it. But it assumes some things like the array list is non empty, etc. Adapt for your use case:

```
from itertools import chain

def hstack_with_zeros(array_list, gap_size):
    shape = array_list[0].shape
    head = list(chain(*[(arr, np.zeros((shape[0], gap_size))) for arr in array_list[:-1]]))
    return np.hstack(head + [array_list[-1]])
```

Example:

```
In [10]: hstack_with_zeros([arr1, arr2], 5)
Out[10]:
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  10.,  11.,  12.]])
```

Comment: but if there are more than two arrays, actually I have to do it for multiple times and every time the number of arrays to be concatenated are different

Comment: How do you access the arrays? Do you have a list of arrays, an argument list, something else? Please specify the question fully.

Comment: I have list of arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which also provides the possibility to specify a gap element:

```
def stackWithGaps(arrays, gap_length, gap_element=0):
    # create the gap
    gap = np.full((arrays[0].shape[0],gap_length), gap_element)

    # see how many elements the stack needs
    n = 2*len(arrays)-1

    # initialize the stack with gaps only
    stack = [gap]*n

    # overwrite every second element with one from the array
    stack[::2] = arrays

    # finally stack our stack
    return np.hstack(stack)
```

The function in action:

```
In [8]: stackWithGaps([arr1,arr2],5)
Out[8]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  10.,  11.,  12.]])

In [9]: stackWithGaps([arr1,arr2],5,np.nan)
Out[9]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  10.,  11.,  12.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `hstack` uses an iteration:

```
arrs = [atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]
return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
```

All the 'cover' functions for `concatenate` iterate over the input list to massage the arrays into the correct shape.  You should not be afraid of this sort of iteration.  It's one thing to iterate over a 1000 rows of an array to do a sum, quite another to iterate over a list of 30 arrays prior to concatenating.

If your input arrays all had the same number of columns, you could `vstack` them, `hstack` on an array of zeros, and reshape that.  But since your input arrays can have differing numbers of columns, you can't do that.  So you are stuck with some sort of iteration that interleave the zeros arrays.

For example:

construct the list of arrays:

```
In [116]: arrs = []
In [117]: for i in range(4):
    arrs.append(np.arange(i,i+2*i).reshape(2,i))

In [122]: pad = np.zeros((2,1))
In [123]: np.concatenate([np.concatenate([i,pad],1) for i in arrs],1)
Out[123]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  4.,  5.,  0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  0.]])
```

The inner `concatenate` pads each array with the zeros.  I first tried using `np.pad` for this, but its inputs are too complicated.  Plus it ends up using `concatenate` anyways.

I could also construct the equivalent of `[arr[0], pad, arr[1], pad, ...]`, but to do that I have to 'flatten' this array: `[(i,pad) for i in arrs]`.

```
In [132]: ll=[(i,pad) for i in arrs]
In [133]: fl=list(itertools.chain(*ll))  # flatten list of tuples
In [134]: np.concatenate(fl,1)
```